# Send Cloud code from Xamarin.Android on Parse Server with Firebase

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, parse-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging

im trying to send cloud code from Xamarin.Android on a Parse server while using Firebase.

I can recieve notifications from dashboard.

Im using this code to send Cloud code:

```
        ParseClient.Initialize(new ParseClient.Configuration
        {
            ApplicationId = GetString(Resource.String.parse_server_app_id),
            WindowsKey = GetString(Resource.String.parse_server_dotnet_key),
            Server = GetString(Resource.String.parse_server_URL)
        });
        ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.CurrentInstallation;
        installation.Add("GCMSenderId", "853939160295");
        List<String> channels = new List<String>();
        channels.Add("parse_user_channel");
        installation.Add("channels", channels);
        installation.SaveAsync();
    ParsePush.SubscribeAsync("parse_user_channel" );
    public void sendAnnouncement(String message, String senderName)
    {

        String channel = "parse_user_channel";
        Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters.Add("accountId", channel);
        parameters.Add("message", message);
        parameters.Add("senderName", senderName);
        parameters.Add("senderId", "theUsersObjectId");
        parameters.Add("useMasterKey", true); //Must have this line

        Task cloudFunctionTask = ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<string>("sendAnnouncement", parameters)
            .ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                Log.Info("AABBCC", "AABBCC");

                if (t.IsFaulted)
                {
                    Log.Info("AABBCC", t.Exception.GetBaseException().Message + "error here");
                }
                Log.Info("AABBCC", t.Result);
            }
    );         
    }
```

This above Code is on Application class.
From my activity im sending the Cloud code with this way:

```
ParseApplication application = (ParseApplication)Application.Context;


application.sendAnnouncement("test", "test");
```

And my Parse Cloud Code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendAnnouncement", function(request, response) {
        var name = request.params.senderName;
        var msg = request.params.message;

        Parse.Push.send({
                channels: [ request.params.accountId ],
                data: {
                        title: name,
                        message: msg,
                        action: "com.hello.announcement.sample.SEND_ANNOUNCEMENT",
                        senderId: request.params.senderId,
                        accountId: request.params.accountId
                }
        }, {
                success: function() {
                        // Push was successful
                        response.success("sendAnnouncement sent");
                },
                error: function(error) {
                        // Handle error
                        response.error("error with sendAnnouncement: " + error);
                },
                useMasterKey: true
        });
});
```

I have try also with that Cloud code and i still get the same log:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendAnnouncement", function(request, response) {
        var name = request.params.senderName;
        var msg = request.params.message;

        Parse.Push.send({
                channels: [ request.params.accountId ],
                data: {
                        title: name,
                        message: msg,
                        action: "com.hello.announcement.sample.SEND_ANNOUNCEMENT",
                        senderId: request.params.senderId,
                        accountId: request.params.accountId
                }
        }, { useMasterKey: true }).then(function() {
                        // Push was successful
                        response.success("sendAnnouncement sent");
                }, function(error) {
                        // Handle error
                        response.error("error with sendAnnouncement: " + error);
});
});
```

I'm pretty sure i can use the **CallFunctionAsync** in a better way.

My shared Code might seems limited but since i can get notifications i get the problem should be on the **cloud code** or the **sendAnnouncement** code.

After i run the above code, on the past pushes on server dashboard i don't see any push send. is there any problem with my code?

On My log i get this:

***03-13 03:06:15.459 I/AABBCC  ( 7059): Invalid function: "sendAnnouncement"error here***

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @Jason my question is: if everything is ok, after running this application.sendAnnouncement("test", "test"); command, should i see a push notification that has been sent on the past pushes section on the server? i see nothing there. Is there a way to get the response from the cloud code?

Answer (score 0):

I had the cloud code saved as test.js

it should be main.js

Now everything work as expected. I didnt see that coming :D